# gplot2 grids overlap out of boundary

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I create points uniformly in [0,1] and each point has observations. But ggpolot shows some observations larger than 1 which is outside of the boundary. How come this can happen even though coordinates are within 0 and 1 range? Do you have any idea how to avoid this?

```
x=runif(10^6)
y=runif(10^6)
z=rnorm(10^6)

new.data=data.frame(x,y,z)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=new.data) + stat_summary_2d(fun = mean, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s an issue related to the grid used for binning.
Let’s use a smaller example.

```r
set.seed(42)
x=runif(10^3)
y=runif(10^3)
z=rnorm(10^3)

new.data=data.frame(x,y,z)

library(ggplot2)

(g <- ggplot(data=new.data) + 
    stat_summary_2d(fun = mean, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z))  +
    geom_point(aes(x, y)))
```

[image]

Now let’s zoom at that box on the upper left corner

```r
g + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.02, 0.075), ylim = c(0.99, 1.035), 
                    expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

As you can see, that box starts below y = 1 but extends above that value
because you are binning observations according to some binwidth.
The same phenomenon can occur if you use a histogram.

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x = runif(1000, 0, 1)), aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram()
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

In `geom_histogram` this can be aboided by setting the `boundary` argument
to 0 and the amount of bins to a multiple of the total length.

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x = runif(1000, 0, 1)), aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(boundary = 0, binwidth = 0.1)
```

[image]

So the solution in your case is to set binwidth to 1/n where n is
an integer

```r
ggplot(data=new.data) + 
    stat_summary_2d(fun = mean, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z), binwidth = 0.1)  +
    geom_point(aes(x, y))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: aye, but using `binwidth=0.1` (to `stat_summary2d()`) for your example does something similar and for the @Justin's q: `binwidth=0.025` accomplishes similar objectives.

Comment: Thank you Elio, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
set.seed(1)
x=runif(10^6)
```

Here's what's [going on](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-bin2d.r#L105) behind [the scenes](https://github.com/cran/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-summary-2d.r#L98):

```
bins <- 30L
range <- range(x)
origin <- 0L
binwidth <- diff(range)/bins
breaks <- seq(origin, range[2] + binwidth, binwidth)
bins <- cut(x, breaks, include.lowest = TRUE, right = TRUE, dig.lab = 7)
table(bins)
# ...
# (0.8999984,0.9333317]   (0.9333317,0.9666649]   (0.9666649,0.9999982] 
# 33217                   33039                   33297 
# (0.9999982,1.033331] 
# 1 
max(x)
# [1] 0.9999984
```

> How come this can happen even though coordinates are within 0 and 1
>   range

1. binning starts at `0` (not a the minimum value)
2. each bin has a size of `binwidth`
3. there's a final bin that ends at the maximum value + `binwidth`, which gets the maximum value

> Do you have any idea how to avoid this?

One way would be to define your own breaks:

```
ggplot(data=new.data) + stat_summary_2d(fun = mean, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z), breaks = seq(0, 1, .1))
```